# How can i save values in database using rails association?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody please help me to resolve my small issue ?Actually i have Admin model and it has many images which will be stored in Image model.I am facing little bit problem to store some images in Image table via Admin model.I am giving my codes below.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Please check my below codes:

## views/posts/adminpage.html.erb:

```
<div class="name-div">
Name:<%= @admin.email %>
</div>
<% if signed_in? %>
<div class="button-div">
<a href="/sessions/destroy"><button type="button" class="styled-button-10">LOG OUT</button></a>
</div>
<% end %>
<h1>WEBSITE USER DETAILS</h1>
<table class="gradienttable">
<tr>
    <th><p>User id</p></th>
    <th><p>User name</p></th>
    <th><p>User email</p></th>
    <th><p>User image</p></th>
</tr>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
    <td><p><%= post.id %></p></td>
    <td><p><%= post.name %></p></td>
    <td><p><%= post.email %></p></td>
    <td><p><%= image_tag(post.picture_url, :width => 90,:height => 90 ) if post.picture.present? %></p></td>
    <td><p><%= link_to 'Delete', posts_deluser_path(:id => post.id), :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                                     :method => :delete %> </p></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<center><h1>Add content</h1></center>
<table class="img-table">
<tr>
<th>Add 1st image</th>
<th>Add 2nd image</th>
<th>Add 3rd image</th>
<th>Add 4th image</th>
<th>Add 5th image</th>
</tr>
<%= form_for :images,:url => {:action => "addimage",:controller => "images",:id => @admin.id  } do |f| %>
<tr>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture1 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture2 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture3 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture4 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture5 %></td>
<td><%= f.submit "ADD" %></td>
<td id="addimg"><button type="button" style="cursor:pointer;">Update</button></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<table class="update-image">
<tr>
<th>1st image</th>
<th>2nd image</th>
<th>3rd image</th>
<th>4th image</th>
<th>5th image</th>
</tr>
<%= form_for :images,:url => {:action => "updateimage",:controller => "images" } do |f| %>
<tr>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture1 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture1 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture1 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture1 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture1 %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

## controller/images_controller.rb

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
    def addimage
        @admin=Admin.find(params[:admin_id])
        @images=@admin.images.create(params[:images])
        redirect_to :action => 'adminpage',:controller => 'posts'
    end
    def updateimage

    end
end
```

## routes.rb

```
Blogpost::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "posts#index"
  get "posts/login" => "posts#login"
  get "posts/show" => "posts#show"
  post "posts/logincreate" => "posts#logincreate"
  get "posts/admin" => "posts#admin"
  post "sessions/adminlogin" => "sessions#adminlogin"
  get "posts/adminpage" => "posts#adminpage"
  delete "posts/deluser" => "posts#deluser"
   get "sessions/destroy" => "sessions#destroy"
   get "posts/content" => "posts#content"
   post "images/addimage" => "images#addimage"
    post "images/updateimage" => "images#updateimage"
  resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
end
```

## images.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
  attr_accessible :picture1, :picture2, :picture3, :picture4, :picture5
  mount_uploader :picture ,PictureUploader
end
```

## admin.rb

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :confirmation => true
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
  has_many :images
end
```

## db/migrate/20150220093517_create_images.rb

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string :picture1
      t.string :picture2
      t.string :picture3
      t.string :picture4
      t.string :picture5
      t.references :admin

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :images, :admin_id
  end
end
```

Please check the above codes and try to help me to store images in database via Admin model.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below

```
   <%= form_for :images,:url => {:action => "addimage",:controller => "images" } , :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<tr>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture1 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture2 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture3 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture4 %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :picture5 %></td>
<td><%= f.hidden_field :admin_id, :value => @admin.id %></td> #add the admin Id 
</tr>
<% end %>
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
  attr_accessible :picture1, :picture2, :picture3, :picture4, :picture5, :admin_id
  mount_uploader :picture ,PictureUploader
end
```